# Draggable background boxes as sliders in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, background, slider

I am currently using XCode 8 and Swift 3 and I have been  searching and haven't been able to find a way of being able to complete what I want to do - basically, I want to be able to have a progression box behind text which I am able to drag from the left to the right to be able to have a 0-100 slider.  I have created a mock-up to be able to attempt to describe what I am attempting to achieve, the progression bars in the background should be able to be slideable which will update the progression number once it has let go.

Any help would be appreciated on this as I have been stumped for awhile now.

Here is the mock-up:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One method: use a `UISlider` "under" the labels. Might be able to get away with tint colors - if not, then transparent images for thumb and max track image, and just-a-little translucent image for min track image.